# Why was Thor's hammer never used again?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

After SG1 broke Thor's hammer to let Teal'c through (in [SG1: Thor's Hammer](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Thor%27s_Hammer)), the Asgard eventually repaired it (in [SG1: Thor's Chariot](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Thor%27s_Chariot))

However, there were many situations after where Goa'uld had taken hosts and the Tokra could not be contacted (sorry, I forgot the specific episodes...I just binge-watched all 10 seasons over 2 weeks)

Why was Thor's hammer not used to remove symbiotes, for example, when Sam's father Jacob was dying?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last time we see Cimmeria is at the end of *SG1: Thor's Chariot* where we're told that the Asgard *intend* to rebuild Thor's Hammer.

> **GAIRWYN:** *For us, there is still much to rebuild. Thor has promised to leave an Asgard teacher behind to help us.*
>
> **TEAL'C:** *Then Cimmeria will be a safe world again. That is good.*
>
> **GAIRWYN:** *Yes, it is. I'm to tell you that Thor's new Hammer will make an exception for the one called Teal'c. You are welcome here anytime.*

Given that the Asgard have [problems of their own](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY5c3.gif), it's possible that they didn't actually rebuild it (knowing the Goa'uld would likely arrive by ship instead of through the stargate anyway), merely relying on the threat of their retribution to prevent any further invasion.

Comment: I personally intend to do lots of things that I don't actually do.

Comment: Excellent theory!